# Correct Syntax for Sum and Count Query

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I am trying to calculate a total for entry fees paid by members and a total for entry fees paid by non members. Members paid $60 to race & non members paid $90.

I have a table called `race_entries`  with the following table columns & values

```
FormId     | FieldName    |  FieldValue |  FieldName  | FieldValue  | FieldName  |  FieldValue

 4               Race Entry       Member        event             Spring 1        class             Shifter
```

I have tried this

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT SUM(COUNT) FROM race_entries WHERE `FieldValue`='Member' AND `FormId`='4' * 60");
$directoryLayout.="Total Member Fees: " . "$" . $db->loadResult() . "<br/>";
```

and this

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT SUM(COUNT * 60) FROM race_entries WHERE `FieldValue`='Member' AND `FormId`='4');
$directoryLayout.="Total Member Fees: " . "$" . $db->loadResult() . "<br/>";
```

and a few other variations but neither of them work. I know very little about MySql but I am trying to teach myself and learn. I have managed to write a few queries to calculate straight forward totals using `SUM` when it just totals a numeric value in a field. But I don't know how to do a Count of the number of occurrences of a text string and then multiply it by 60.

Comment: can you give bit more clear information about your question

Comment: you need it in a single query result?

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(`FieldValue`) * 60 as members_fees FROM t2zt1_rsform_submission_values WHERE `FieldValue`='Member' AND `FormId`='4'");
$directoryLayout.="Total Member Fees: $" . $db->loadResult() . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thank you Sathya for your response! 

I tried that code, it shows no result on this page
http://www.racekarts.com/index.php?option=com_rsform&view=directory&Itemid=670&lang=en 

THe result should display after the text "Total Member Fees"

Can you tell me what 'id' is? And what do I do with "members_fees" ?

Comment: In place of `id` it could be any column from your table. `members_fees` is the var in which you will get your final calculated result.

Comment: SO I can put this? 

$db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(`FieldValue`) * 60 as members_fees FROM t2zt1_rsform_submission_values WHERE `FieldValue`='Member' AND `FormId`='4'");
$directoryLayout.="Total Member Fees: $" . $db->loadResult() . "<br/>";

Comment: How do I get the variable "members_fees" to display in the report on the website? Should I put "$db->loadresult(members_fees);"  ?

Comment: Its depend on the framework you using. How it exactly provides you data for the single coulmn from the result.

Comment: This code produced the line at the bottom of the report "Total Passes: $45" 

$db->setQuery("SELECT SUM((`FieldValue`) * 5) FROM t2zt1_rsform_submission_values WHERE `FieldName`='passes' AND `FormId`='4'");
$directoryLayout.="  Total Passes: " . "$" . $db->loadResult() . "<br/>";

Comment: Ok so you can try changing SUM with COUNT and multiply with 60 check.

Comment: It works now! This code produced a total $db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(`FieldValue`) * 60 as members_fees FROM t2zt1_rsform_submission_values WHERE `FieldValue`='Member' AND `FormId`='4'");
$directoryLayout.="Total Member Fees: $" . $db->loadResult() . "<br/>";

Comment: I guess it just needed a variable defined (members_fees) even though I didn't use it?

Comment: That's great. Its fine if you do or not :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't vote your response "up" as I don;t have enough "reputation" yet, but I will when I get enough reputation. Thank you!